# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: first_app.html

Tags: html, python, flask

escribo por este medio para ver si alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente problema. Estoy estudiando Flask web application with HTML y obtengo el siguiente

> error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: first_app.html.

Lo que me parece extraño es que ese template llamado **first_app.html** si existe en el directorio.

El directorio es :

```
1st_flask_app_2/
app.py
static/
style.css
templates/
_formhelpers.html
first_app.html
hello.html
```

El código de app.py es como sigue:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from wtforms import Form, TextAreaField, validators

app = Flask(__name__)

class HelloForm(Form):
    sayhello = TextAreaField('',[validators.DataRequired()])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = HelloForm(request.form)
    return render_template('first_app.html', form=form)

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    form = HelloForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = request.form['sayhello']
        return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
    return render_template('first_app.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Static es una carpeta que contiene style.css con el siguiente código:

```
body {
font-size: 2em;
}
```

Templates es una carpeta que contiene los siguientes HTML:

1) _formhelpers.html con el siguiente código:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
<dt>{{ field.label }}
<dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
{% if field.errors %}
<ul class=errors>
{% for error in field.errors %}
<li>{{ error }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
</dd>
</dt>
{% endmacro %}
```

2) first_app.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>First app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',
filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<div>What's your name?</div>
<form method=post action="/hello">
<dl>
{{ render_field(form.sayhello) }}
</dl>
<input type=submit value='Say Hello' name='submit_btn'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

3) hello.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>First app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',
filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello {{ name }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Me parece raro porque ayer me arrojaba el mismo error para ejecutar : "Hi, this is my first flask web app " y finalmente hoy día lo logré. Ahora estoy tratando de hacer la segunda app y por más que trato no logro nada. Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

En tu `app.py` reemplaza esta línea:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Por:

```
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
```

Con esto estás definiendo la ubicación de los templates.

Documentación de flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/

Comment: muchas gracias fredyfx por tu respuesta, ya solucioné el problema ... el problema era que la carpeta templates no iba dentro de la carpeta static , saludos !

Comment: ¡Excelente hermano! me alegra saberlo, ahora, procede a agregar la respuesta y marcarla como aceptada en 24 horas, serás el héroe de más usuarios con el mismo escenario :D

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que la carpeta templates no iba dentro de la carpeta static si no que iba dentro de la carpeta 1st_flask_app_2. El directorio es como sigue:

```
1st_flask_app_2/
    app.py
    static/
       style.css
    templates/
      _formhelpers.html
      first_app.html
      hello.html
```